# Check how my process was killed

Tags: linux, debian, process, webserver, node.js

I'm currently running a simple Node.JS server with [express.js](http://expressjs.com) on my RaspberryPi with Debian installed on it. Everything works fine, but every morning I wake up to see my server isn't running anymore (the server process I started with `node main.js`).

My first guess was, that the Pi has some kind of sleep mode, which it enters after a couple of hours without traffic/etc, and which shuts down the server, but I also run a dydns-client, which is still up every morning.

Is there a way to *track* a process after I started it to check tomorrow morning, what *killed* my process or why it ended?

The server itself looks pretty simple and I don't think there is some kind of **auto-shutdown** I missed. Here is the code I used.

```
var express = require('express');
var path    = require('path');

var server  = express();
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.listen(1337);
console.log("Server listening (PORT: " + 1337 + ") ...");
```

Any idea what to do, to keep the server running/find out what is the stopping reason?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of some process management tools like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) or [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

If you are using pm2, you can do `pm2 start main.js`. It will monitor and restart the process if it gets killed. You can find the error reason in pm2 logs located inside ~/.pm2

You can run `pm2 startup` to generate the init script that allows pm2 to run on boot.

`pm2 save` saves the current process list so that they can be run on system reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer `forever` seems quite interesting, but I actually received [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47139/http-server-stops-after-some-time?noredirect=1#comment70299_47139) post, which solved my problem (starting via SSH).